# Как передать логи из Flask/Python в S3 Amazon Storage?

Tags: python, flask, amazon

Разрабываю приложение и планирую хостить его на Heroku.

Приложение использует логгер и складывает логи в файл.

Код логгера такой:

```
from loguru import logger  # удобный логгер ошибок - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ndEeGDVqD4
logger.add('logs/debug.json',
           format="{time} {level} {message}",
           level="ERROR",
           rotation="10:00",
           compression="zip",
           serialize=True)
```

Сам Heroku не позволяет складывать логи (нет прав), поэтому решил передавать логи в S3 Amazon Storage.

Хочу использовать примерно такой код для складывания данных в S3 Amazon:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError

ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'


def upload_to_aws(local_file, bucket, s3_file):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                      aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

    try:
        s3.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file)
        print("Upload Successful")
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("The file was not found")
        return False
    except NoCredentialsError:
        print("Credentials not available")
        return False


uploaded = upload_to_aws('local_file', 'bucket_name', 's3_file_name')
```

Но не могу разобраться как мне соединить эти два куса кода, чтобы в S3 передавались логи. Можете подсказать?

Спасибо.